# Return false doesn't cancel the asp.net postback

Tags: asp.net

I am puzzled why this return false doesn't cancel the post-back.

```
 function validate() {
         return false;
        }



 <asp:Button ID="Button1" type="submit" OnClientClick="validate();" runat="server" Text="send"  />
```

The most crazy part is that the code below DOES cancel the postback, but I need this to happen in the function like above:

```
 <asp:Button ID="Button1" type="submit" OnClientClick="return false;" runat="server" Text="send" style="margin-right:150px;" />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try returning the value from your function, like this

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" type="submit" OnClientClick="return validate();" runat="server" Text="send"  />
```

Otherwise you are just executing a javascript function that returns a boolean.

Answer (score 1):

try using this

```
  <input type"button" id="Button1" onclick="validate();">
```

if you will not need a postback then you do not need an asp:Button

Answer (score 0):

A little extra for *The Jonas Persson*'s answer for those who use their `Button` inside an `UpdatePanel` for AJAX PostBack: when a `Button` is rendered, the onclick attribute will look like

```
<input ...  onclick="OnClientClick_property; generated_ajax_postback();" />
```

To make sure the `generated_ajax_postback();` is executed, you must make `OnClientClick_property` something this: `if (!validate) return false;`

Otherwise it will return `true`, and does not Post Back at all.